# Как написать телеграмм бота который при входе нового участника будет писать сообщение: "Привет {имя участника} добро пожаловать!"

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как написать телеграмм бота который при входе нового участника будет писать сообщение: "Привет {имя участника} добро пожаловать!"

Comment: вам нужна библиотека python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам понадобится установить библиотеку `python-telegram-bot`

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

После установки библиотеки, вам нужно создать бота через BotFather в Telegram, получить токен и добавить его в ваш код.

Для того, чтобы ваш бот приветствовал новых участников чата, вам нужно создать обработчик события `MessageHandler` и использовать методы `message.new_chat_members` и `message.chat` для получения информации о новых участниках и чате соответственно.

Пример кода для вашей задачи:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

def welcome_new_member(update, context):
    for new_member in update.message.new_chat_members:
        message = f"Привет, {new_member.first_name}! Добро пожаловать в чат {update.message.chat.title}!"
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=message)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add a handler for new chat members
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.new_chat_members, welcome_new_member))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Замените `YOUR_TOKEN_HERE` на ваш токен бота, сохраните скрипт и запустите его